# Micropython Urequest Google app script json url

Tags: python, json, curl, request, micropython

I use the D1 Mini to get Google app script data by MicroPython urequests and get the error as below:

```
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
TLS buffer overflow, record size: 6682 (+5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "urllib/urequest.py", line 32, in urlopen
OSError: (-257, 'RECORD_OVERFLOW')
>>>
```

The code I'm running is:

```
import urllib.urequest
f = urllib.urequest.urlopen('script.google.com/macros/s/…)
# f.code
# f.headers
c=f.read()
c.decode("utf-8")[3:6]
```

Comment: It would help if we could see your code. Also, the D1 mini is a severely memory-constrained device; if you're trying to fetch content into memory the document may simply be too large.

Comment: The code is: import urllib.urequest
f = urllib.urequest.urlopen('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyw9eyMMJVuHb_dFsRxRskh4iFKAO7CAacKGoLGoSksfmd1qnvX7SXSH8eNLtVtl48-cg/exec')
# f.code
# f.headers
c=f.read()
c.decode("utf-8")[3:6]

Comment: It's always a better idea to edit your question rather than adding code in a comment (because it's not possible to format code correctly in a comment).

Comment: I would expect that code to fail because you're missing the scheme (`https://`) on `script.google.com`. Otherwise the code looks fine, and it's probably just a memory issue.

Comment: Try again This code and not working‍♂️:import urllib.urequest
f = urllib.urequest.urlopen(“https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyw9eyMMJVuHb_dFsRxRskh4iFKAO7CAacKGoLGoSksfmd1qnvX7SXSH8eNLtVtl48-cg/exec')
c=f.read()
c.decode("utf-8")[3:6]